# how to pass json string in anchor tag mvc 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to send data to action and return different view with viewmodel object .

I want to send json string to action from index.cshtml page and want to redirect or return to Tax.cshtml page with viewmodel object.
razor:

```
  <li class="mt5"><a id="noOfCart" href="@Url.Action("ReviewOrder", "Tax",new {storedTaxyear=localStorage.getItem("taxyear")} )"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg hover1 textwhite"></i><span class="shoppingbadge"></span></a></li>
```

controller

```
 public ActionResult ReviewOrder(string storedTaxyear)
 {
      ViewBag.FormName = 1;
      ServicesCategoryList objviewmodel = new ServicesCategoryList();

      return View("Tax", objviewmodel);       
 }
```

It is showing localstorage does not exist

Comment: You can't pass a Javascript variable to a Razor variable. Try to put localStorage.getItem("taxyear") in a hidden field first and then pass it's value to the tag

Answer (score 0):

Razor code executes on server side while javascript executes on client side, you would need to do it in the client side click event of the anchor tag like:

```
<li class="mt5">
   <a id="noOfCart" href="@Url.Action("ReviewOrder", "Tax")">
     <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg hover1 textwhite"></i>
       <span class="shoppingbadge"></span>
   </a>
</li>
```

and then in jquery add the query string value like:

```
$(function(){

    $("#noOfCart").click(function(){
        // get jquery object reference of current clicked anchor element
        var self = $(this);
        // update href with the query string 
        self.attr("href",self.attr("href")+"?storedTaxyear="+localStorage.getItem("taxyear"));

    });
});
```

Comment: yeah whatever is in the key of localstorage will be passed in query string

Comment: how will i hide that big url

Comment: you need to post then thst json instead of a get request

Comment: i try ajax post method but its not redirecting to another view